# How can I find out all the methods defined for a class in R?

Tags: oop, class, r, methods

In R, I want to get an idea of what I can do with a particular class (specifically, the "Mart" class from the "biomaRt" package in BioConductor). I would like to see all the methods that are defined for this class. Is there a way to do this?

Note: The `methods` function does not do what I want. That function lists all the classes for which a specific method is defined, not all the methods defined for a class.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ah, but `methods` does do what you want.  Read `?methods` carefully and you will see the `class=` argument is what you're looking for.

```
require(zoo)
methods(class="zoo")
```

S4 classes are similar, but you need to use `showMethods` instead.

```
require(timeSeries)
showMethods(classes="timeSeries")
```

Comment: For S4 it's often helpful to add `where=getNamespace("timeSeries")`

Answer (score 2):

If your class is an S3 class then you use the methods function, but specify the class argument.

If it is an S4 class then use showMethods.